# Проект Эйлера: Задача 5. Наименьшее кратное

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеется следующая [задача](https://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/5.html)

Написал вот такой код:

```
from random import randint as random

own = []

while len(own) != 1:
    num = random(1, 100000)
    temp = []

    # Генерация 20-ти чисел которые будут делиться на случайное число.
    for i in range(1, 21):
        while i != 20:
            temp.append(int(num) / i)

            # Проверка на наличие дробного числа в списке.
            for o in temp:
                if type(o) == float:
                    temp.clear()
                else:
                    continue
                if len(temp) == 20:
                    own.append(num)
                else:
                    pass
```

Результата никакого он не выдаёт, просто работает и всё. Большая просьба -  объяснить, что не так с кодом, и как мне можно написать его для правильной работы. Может Вы знаете алгоритмические способы, подходящие для такой задачи - я с удовольствием изучу их и использую. Но, пожалуйста, не нужно писать сам код который решает проблему, т.к. я начинающий в этой области - хочу сам попрактиковаться в написании кода. Спасибо! :)

Comment: Вам наименьшее общее кратное надо найти? https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/math.html#math.lcm

Comment: Вот вопрос: https://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/5.html . Прошу прощения что забыл указать в описании вопроса.

Comment: Я привёл ссылку на функцию, с помощью которой можно найти НОК. А ссылку на задачу вы можете вставить в сам вопрос с помощью кнопки править, если надо

Comment: Прошу прощения, я правильно понял что это функция - "math.lcm"?

Comment: Да, но она доступна с 3.9 версии питона. Если у вас меньше версия, то берите произведение элементов и делите на их `math.gcd`, которая появилась раньше. Все формулы есть на той же википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наименьшее_общее_кратное

Comment: Можно уточнить, что именно делает данная функция?

Comment: Вычисляет наименьшее общее кратное переданных аргументов

Comment: Какая строка вашей программы должна выдавать результат?

Comment: У вас задача детерминирована. Зачем вам случайные числа?

Comment: Приведите задачу в текстовом виде в вопросе, а не по ссылке

Answer (score 2):

1. Разложим каждое число по степеням простых чисел.
2. Результат это наименьшее общее кратное - т.е. берем каждое простое число в наибольшей степени

   ```
   primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
   res = {2: 0, 3: 0, 5: 0, 7: 0, 11: 0, 13: 0, 17: 0, 19: 0}


   def get_powers(n, primes):
       pr = {}
       for p in primes:
           if n % p == 0:
               pr[p] = 0
           while (n % p == 0):
               pr[p] += 1
               n = n / p
       return pr


   def merge_powers(pr, res):
       for p in pr:
           res[p] = max(pr[p], res[p])
       return res


   n = 20

   for i in range(2, n + 1):
       pr = get_powers(i, primes)
       res = merge_powers(pr, res)

   result = 1

   for p in res:
      if res[p]>0:
           result = result * (p**res[p])


   print(result)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

В `for i in range(1,21):` есть цикл `while i != 20`, он выполняется бесконечно,  начнёт выполнятся при i = 1, а в самом цикле i не изменяется.
*Задачу можно решить с помощью разложения на множители.*

Answer (score 1):

```
def lcm(a, b):
    m = a * b
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a > b:
            a %= b
        else:
            b %= a
    return m // (a + b)


while 1:
    try:
        x = int(input('a = '))
        y = int(input('b = '))
        print('НОК:', lcm(x, y))
    except ValueError:
        break
```

---

[source](https://younglinux.info/python/task/lcm)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема вашего кода в том , что в нём отсутствует `return` или же `print` поэтому никакого вывода в консоль не происходит. Я знаю , что вы просили не скидывать вам полный код , но всё же рекомендую ознакомиться с данной [ссылкой](http://pythoneuler.blogspot.com/2016/09/5.html) в ней разобран весь алгоритм простым и понятными языком. Если вы его как следует изучите в будущем вам будет проще.